# How to make proguard-maven-plugin obfuscate code without reading dependencies in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I found that when proguard-maven-plugin confuses the code, proguard will read the dependencies in pom.xml.

But in fact, the obfuscated jar does not contain dependencies. Is there any way to prevent dependencies from being read when obfuscated?